# First Amalgamated Church

Tags: futurama, religion

In Futurama there are a series of religions, the most diverse being the robot faith. The reason for that is because Religions of Earth joined into one religion.

Why and when did the Religions combine into one Religion?

There are differences in today's religions, so how can they form the First Amalgamated Church without having any problems?

Comment: Maybe they realised that, similar to M-Theory, the same thing can appear with many different shapes but really is still the same?

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the episode ["When Aliens Attack"](http://theinfosphere.org/When_Aliens_Attack), a major religious event occurred in 2443: **The second coming of Jesus!**

That was probably quite the game-changer, spiritually speaking. Jesus himself was Jewish, is the savior of the Christian faith, and is a prophet of Islam. That puts him in a key position to be able to unite these varied religions into a cohesive (albeit [more vague](http://theinfosphere.org/Changstein#Quotes)) belief system, even as he was apparently declaring war on Earth's long-since-outdated VHS collections. It seems like a reasonable conjecture that the [First Amalgamated Church](http://theinfosphere.org/First_Amalgamated_Church) is what arose from the ashes of all that magnetic tape.

Incidentally, it appears Catholicism didn't join them, they just [moved to space](http://theinfosphere.org/Space_Catholicism) instead.

Comment: And was probably based on Siddartha (The Buddha).

Answer (score 4):

One *possible* explanation (besides my not-so-serious remark in the comment above), could be the rising pressure from the [Church of Trek](http://theinfosphere.org/Church_of_Trek) which attracted more and more believers, possibly drawing members from the more traditional religions, such as

> Christianity, Judaism, Islam, Hinduism and Buddhism as well as
>   agnosticism <sup>[[theinfosphere.org]](http://theinfosphere.org/Religion#First_Amalgamated_Church)</sup>

Such that they decided to unite. If this *theory* is true, that would mean, the First Amalgamated Church formed somewhere in the 23rd century.

Comment: Would that mean that [Father Changestein El-Gamal](http://theinfosphere.org/Father_Changstein_El-Gamal) changed his name to that?

Comment: @DampeS8N: I don't get your question. If my theory applies, it's safe to assume the Church existed in its current form, way before he was born.

Comment: @bitmask But nobody else has a name like that. I assumed it implied that he created the religion. And named it similar to himself.